# For the line $y = mx$, let $m = tan(\theta)$. Write $f(x, mx)$ as a function of $\theta$..?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a problem, and I am not sure how to solve it.
This is the problem from my book:

> let $f(x, y)$ be given by the function: $$ f(x, y) =  \begin{cases} 
>        \frac{2xy}{x^2 + y^2}, & (x, y) \ne (0, 0) \\
>        \
>       0, & (x, y) = (0, 0)      \end{cases} $$ for the line $y = mx$, let $m = tan(\theta)$. Write $f(x, mx)$ as a function of $\theta$.
>
> Use the
>   answer to the above to show how the value of $f(x, y)$ varies with the
>   line’s angle of
>
> inclination.

Comment: Do a direct substitution for $y = x\tan\theta$, use trigonometric indentity $1 + \tan^2\theta = \sec^2\theta$ in the denominator for further simplification. You will notice, that the x term disappears completely.

Comment: Note that,
$$\dfrac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}=\dfrac{2x^2\tan \theta}{x^2+x^2\tan^2\theta}=\dfrac{2\tan\theta}{\sec^2\theta}=\sin2\theta$$

Hence, $$g(\theta)=\begin{cases}\sin 2\theta &\theta\ne0\\0&\theta=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks heaps @user170039, That was just what I was after. Corey :)

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Start by trying to write $f$ as a function of $r$ and $\theta$ (as in polar coordinates).